# ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' while installing Tweakpane

Tags: javascript, npm, package, npm-install

I am new to JS.
I have been following a course on Domestika where I am needed to install the [Tweakpane](https://cocopon.github.io/tweakpane/) package. I am using Git Bash to install the package. (I have been able to successfully install other packages the same way).
Here is how I tried installing it:

```
$ npm install --save tweakpane
$ npm install --save-dev @tweakpane/core
```

While installing it didn't give any error. But when I tried to open my JS file it showed the following error:

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
line 7788
sketches\node_modules\tweakpane\dist\tweakpane.js
export { BladeApi, ButtonApi, FolderApi, ListBladeApi, ListInputBindingApi, Pane, Semver, SeparatorBladeApi, SliderBladeApi, SliderInputBindingApi, TabApi, TabPageApi, TextBladeApi, TpChangeEvent, VERSION };
^
```

Can anyone guide me as to how to solve this issue? I searched online and found few instances connected to other packages, and did try those methods (installing the core was one of them), but it didn't really work, maybe due to some mistake that I did.

I would be much obliged if anyone could illuminate on this error and steps I can follow to solve it. If any other info is required please do let me know.

**EDIT:** I did a workaround. I checked Tweakpane's GitHub and found that they shifted to ES modules from version 4 (which is the latest and is the version that got installed on my system). So, I uninstalled that package, and installed the specific version 3. Now it is working fine or as expected.

But I would still appreciate some information regarding ES modules and how to fix that error I was getting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall Tweakpane first:

```
npm uninstall tweakpane
```

and then install a lower version:

```
npm i tweakpane@3.1.9
```

This approach worked for me.